# Getting error on Firefox 51.0 using Selenium 3.0.1

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I am newbie to selenium WebDriver.

my code is below

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
public class DropdownHandling {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "F:\\Study material\\Selenium\\geckodriver-v0.13.0-arm7hf\\geckodriver");
    WebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver();
    d.manage().window().maximize();
    d.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
    WebElement list =d.findElement(By.xpath("//a[span[text()='Women']]"));
    Actions a = new Actions(d);
    a.moveToElement(list).perform();
    d.findElement(By.xpath("//a[span[text()='Flats']]")).click();
    }
}
```

I am trying to navigate to Women category and select flats under footwear category on flipkart.com. But I am unable to figure out the error.

Output of the Console is given below:

```
Jan 31, 2017 1:10:11 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:34970 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'MKN', ip: '192.168.0.106', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:259)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:238)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
    at DropdownHandling.main(DropdownHandling.java:14)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:34970 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: What version of geckodriver are you using? First thing I'd check would be if you're using the version of geckodriver that works with your ff version

Comment: i am using geckodriver-v0.13.0

Comment: A couple more questions, which OS are you using? Which line causes the error? I don't see anything wrong with the code unless OS is an issue, but you could always try the desired capabilities approach. `DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);`

Comment: There error makes it look like the test is trying to run on Windows 10, I've posted an answer based on that. Best of luck!

Comment: Remember also that Actions is a native mouse action, which relies heavily on which driver you loaded.  If necessary, you can get around that by doing a non-native JavaScript using a JavaScriptExecutor.   I am not saying that is the solution, but if you end up being totally stuck, that will temporarily allow you to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're using the wrong driver.

```
"F:\\Study material\\Selenium\\geckodriver-v0.13.0-arm7hf\\geckodriver"
```

Indicates you're using the arm7hf(not windows) driver.

```
System info: host: 'MKN', ip: '192.168.0.106', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86'...
```

Indicates you're using windows 10

Try using the `geckodriver-v0.13.0-win32` driver, or `win64` driver.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: tried using geckodriver-v0.13.0-win32/win64 niether of two is working.

Comment: It's likely you're running into several different issues. When you used the windows driver, did you get the same error message? Or did it fail on something else?